# SQL Query to display dates weekly from current date

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle19c

I have a requirement to display dates every week starting from current date for 48 months.

I was wondering if it is possible through SQL or i will have to write a function to achieve it.

Below is my SQL so far :-

```
SELECT
  CALENDAR_DATE
FROM
  CALENDAR --My Table Name
WHERE
  (
   CALENDAR_DATE  >=  trunc(sysdate)
   AND
   CALENDAR_DATE  <=  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 48)-1
  )
```

This would give me output as

```
9/10/2020
9/11/2020
9/12/2020
9/13/2020
```

Expected Output :-

```
 9/10/2020
   9/17/2020
   9/24/2020
   10/01/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE  >=  trunc(sysdate) AND
      CALENDAR_DATE  <=  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 48) - 1 AND
      MOD(CALENDAR_DATE - TRUNC(sysdate), 7) = 0
```

This uses the `mod()` operation on the date difference.  You can also check the day of the week:

```
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE  >=  trunc(sysdate) AND
      CALENDAR_DATE  <=  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 48) - 1 AND
      TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE, 'DY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DY')
```